# Teach Zabbix to monitor service status

Tags: service, zabbix

I know that Zabbix can monitor any service on Linux machine via two options:

- scan particular tcp or udp port, on which the service is bound
- or count the service processes with `proc.num[<processname>]`

It is totally counter-intuitive, because I can spawn processes with the same executable name and they will deceive Zabbix. I'd prefer to use standard `service <servicename> status` or `systemctl status name.service` tool. But there are no standard way to use it from Zabbix except `system.run[cmd]`

Could you help me to write templates for monitoring a particular service state. We want to use different OSes like Centos 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 distributions. It is pity but `service <servicename> status` is completely different in listed operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Linux services are managed by `systemd` (Centos 7+, Ubuntu 16+, ...), then you can use https://github.com/cavaliercoder/zabbix-module-systemd. It uses standard [systemd D-Bus communication](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) - that's what `systemctl` does under the hood.

Comment: And what should I use if there are no `systemd` (like Ubuntu 14)?

Comment: non systemd systems = wild wild west = you have to parse output of init scripts

Answer (score 15):

You can also add the following UserParameters in zabbix_agentd.conf to monitor service status in  systemd systems. For non-systemd the OS doesn't really monitor service status, the various bash script "status" arguments are often unreliable.

```
UserParameter=systemd.unit.is-active[*],systemctl is-active --quiet '$1' && echo 1 || echo 0
UserParameter=systemd.unit.is-failed[*],systemctl is-failed --quiet '$1' && echo 1 || echo 0
UserParameter=systemd.unit.is-enabled[*],systemctl is-enabled --quiet '$1' && echo 1 || echo 0
```

And then e.g. for sshd status create an item with a key like:

```
systemd.unit.is-active[sshd]
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, this is a perfectly valid simple solution, that unlike the accepted answer doesn't have any additional dependencies, and so can in some situations even be the only practical solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

For centos 6 it can be done:

```sh
UserParameter=check_service_status_asterisk,sudo service asterisk status 2> /dev/null | grep -q "is running";echo $?
```

For centos 7 or similar it can be created with:

```sh
UserParameter=check_service_status_grafana,systemctl status grafana-server 2> /dev/null |sed -n 3p |grep -q "running";echo $?
```

or

```sh
UserParameter=check_service_status[*],systemctl status $1 2> /dev/null |sed -n 3p |grep -q "running";echo $?
```